# RSA encryption and decryption in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, rsa

Please help me in the following issue.

```
 RSAEncryptionAndDecryption rsaEncDec = new       RSAEncryptionAndDecryption(document.PublicKey, document.PublicAndPrivateKey);
 string reportContent = rsaEncDec.Decrypt(document.Report).OriginalData;
```

When i use the above code in MVC1, the decryption is working properly, but the same code is not able to decrypt the original string in MVC3..
Encryption code is:

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(bitStrength);

        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(publicKey);

        int keySize = bitStrength / 8;
        byte[] dataToEnc = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(inputData);
        int maxLength = keySize - 42;
        int dataLength = dataToEnc.Length;
        int iterations = dataLength / maxLength;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] tempBytes = new byte[(dataLength - maxLength * i > maxLength) ? maxLength : dataLength - maxLength * i];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(dataToEnc, maxLength * i, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(tempBytes, true);

            Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);

            stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
        }
```

While storing the encoded string in the db., the encrypted string half part is getting stored, due to that it is getting the error.

Encoded string is getting trimmed while storing in DB, this is happening only when i use MVC3, and not MVC1.

I m encrypting the html contents., the encrypted contents are stored with the public and private keys, the same key is getting from the DB, when it is called, but the decryption is not working properly-- only half of the original string is getting generated and stopped with some special characters

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: What is `RSAEncryptionAndDecryption` and why is your question tagged with `visual-studio-2010-beta-2`? Is it what you are using?

Comment: I m using visual studio 2010 software. thats y...

Comment: What about `RSAEncryptionAndDecryption`? How is it implemented?

Comment: Added the codes.. Please help me out..

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the character to pad the last block?  If not, what is the default padding character this provider uses?

Comment: We are just passing the string directly. not setting any padding character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to know that while passing the data from the MVC3 to the SQLServer, the string we are passing are not sent properly when we use the SaveOrUpdate() in Nhibernate.

So what i have done is, I have retrieved the ID of the current inserted record and Updated the string using the Update Query..

:) :) Happy Coding.. !!!!!